# Does Git prevent data degradation

Tags: git, zfs, btrfs, data-integrity

I read that ZFS and Btrfs use checksums to prevent [data degradation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation#Data_degradation_in_storage) and I read that Git has integrity through hashing essentially everything with each commit.

I was going to use a Git server on a Linux NAS with Btrfs RAID 1 for storage, but if Git has integrity I guess this wouldn't be necessary (at least not if preventing data degradation is all I want).

**Question:**
So does Git's integrity though hashing essentially everything with each commit prevent or help against bit-rot?

Comment: The famous KDE [near-disaster of 2013](http://jefferai.org/2013/03/29/distillation/) is [somewhat relevant here.](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/KDE-narrowly-avoids-disaster-1829776.html)

Comment: And beware of local clones, git tries to use hard links when you're creating a clone on the same filesystem. That makes cloning incredible fast, but if one object gets corrupted both clones are corrupted.

Comment: Note that if the corruption only occurs for some ancient objects on a given machine, those objects are more likely to be present on other clones of the repo, whereas the (fewer) more recent files might still be usable. I have no idea how this integrates with pack files, though.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Git's hashing only happens at the time commits are created, and from there on the hashes are used to identify the commits.  This in no way ensures the integrity of the files.  Git repos can get corrupted and lose data.  In fact, git has a built-in command to detect this kind of loss, [git fsck](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck), but as the documentation says, you are responsible for restoring any corrupted data from backups.

Comment: Why does `fsck` always look like a bad word to me... I suppose if turns up positive and you don’t have a backup that may be appropriate though ;)

Comment: @CAD97 Programmers are known for these relatively lame puns.  It's quite common actually... Off the top of my head, you have things like sh (shell), bsh (Bourne shell), and then bash (Bourne again shell)... the last one being the lame pun...

Comment: @Nelson don't forget fish

Comment: @CAD97 Hell, the name of git itself can be considered like then when it isn't working right for you.

Comment: @CAD97 - and that's before you run it with flags like fvcctk - because - if you're running it like that, your data may already be "fvcctk"ed. ;)

Answer (score 16):

Depends on what you mean by "prevent".

(First of all, bit-rot is a term with multiple definitions. This question is **not** about [code becoming unrunnable due to lack of maintenance](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bit-rot.html).)

If you mean by "prevent" that it will likely detect corruption by decay of bits, yes, that will work. It will however *not* help to fix that corruption: the hashes only provide error **detection, not correction**.

This is generally what is meant by "integrity": The possibility to *detect* unauthorized/unintended manipulation of data, not the possibility to prevent or correct it.

You would generally still want a RAID1 together with backups (possibly implemented with ZFS snapshots or similar, I am not familiar with the ZFS semantics on RAID1 + snapshots), for several reasons:

- if a disk fails fatally, you either need a RAID1 (or a recent backup) to restore your data; no error correction can correct for a whole disk failing, unless it has a full copy of the data (RAID1). For a short downtime, you essentially must have RAID1.
- if you accidentally delete parts or whole of the repository, you need a backup (RAID1 doesn’t protect you since it immediately reflects the change to all devices)

Block-level RAID1 (e.g. via LVM or similar) with only two disks in itself will *not* protect you against silent decay of data though: the RAID controller cannot know which of the two disks holds the correct data. You need additional information for that, like a checksum over files. This is where the ZSF and btrfs checksums come in: they can be used (which is not to say that they *are* used in these cases, I don’t know how ZFS or btrfs handle things there) to distinguish which of the two disks holds the correct data.

Comment: No need to go with mirroring if you don't want to. ZFS supports striping with 1, 2 or 3 drives' worth of parity; and mirroring with an arbitrary number of drives (including a single drive = no redundancy). My main bulk storage is ZFS with six drives in a RAIDZ2 configuration, which is basically file system level RAID6 (striping with two drives' worth of redundancy). This can detect and recover from the loss of any one of those drives plus uncorrectable errors on one more; or the loss of two drives and no errors elsewhere during resilver; without any loss of data. Backups are still recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> prevent bit-rot

No, it does not, in no way at all. There is no RAID-like redundancy introduced by git. If the files in your `.git` directory suffer bit-rot, you will lose stuff just as usual.

> help against bit-rot?

Yyyy...no. It does not help against bit-rot occuring, but it will help to detect bit-rot. But at no point during normal use does it do so by its own account (well obviously it does when you check out some objects and so on, but not for your history). You would have to create cron jobs to recalculate the hashes from the content and compare them to the actual hashes. It is pretty trivial to do so, as `git` hashes are literally simply the content hashes, it is trivial to recalculate them and `git fsck` does so for you. But when it detects bit-rot, there is nothing in particular that it can do against it. Specifically, as larger chunks are automatically compressed, you will likely incur total chunk loss if a bit in a larger object is flipped.